# How long did Ismaili monotheism last?

Tags: religion, chronology

The Old Testament Prophet Abraham-Ibrahim had two sons, Isaac and Ismail-(who was actually, his oldest son).  Both of Abraham's-Ibrahim's sons were self-identified Monotheists.  It is believed by Muslims (and perhaps by some Historical scholars) that The Kaaba was originally built by Ibrahim and Ismail nearly 4000 years ago, making The Kaaba, the first original monotheistic house of worship in world history.

However, what is less clear-(chronologically speaking), is when did Ismail's direct descendants begin to abandon the Monotheism of his Father, Ibrahim? That is to say, when did Arabia-(as well as many other Semitic lands throughout the greater Middle East), begin to adopt a polytheistic system which would span for millennia until the arrival of Muhammad and the birth of Islam-(circa early 600's CE?)  Did Ancient Middle Eastern polytheism originate with Ismail's children, his grandchildren, his great grandchildren, his great, great grandchildren?, etc. Though it is unlikely that one may able to cite an exact year or decade as to when this religious transition occurred, perhaps one might be able to cite a century-(as its closest origin or approximate beginning point).

It should be noted that since Ismail's time, until Muhammad, there was an obscure Arabian tribe called, "The Hanifs", who, unlike the vast majority of their Semitic counterparts and compatriots, never adopted polytheism, though had steadfastly retained an Ibrahimic Monotheism that remained largely unchanged for millennia-(the Hanifs, along with the Jews, were the only known Monotheistic civilizations, until the arrival of Zoroastrianism in the 600's BCE).

What historical and chronological information is there regarding the origin and longevity of Ismaili Monotheism?

Comment: Please edit with sources. Unless the "perhaps by some Historical scholars" is less made up then it seems, this looks like a question about religion and not history.

Comment: It is an inter relational question that includes both history and religion.

Comment: that's fine... Again, please edit the question to show the sources.

Comment: Welcome to History Stack Exchange. This question appears to be framed in the context of religious studies rather than history. Abraham/Ibrahim is generally understood among historians to be a legendary ancestral and religious figure of the ancient Middle East rather than a specifically identifiable historical person. Could you clarify what sources you are reading and what sort of answer you would accept from the perspective of history?

Comment: Well, I am sorry that my question was closed.  With regard to the figure of Abraham-Ibrahim, he is often considered to have been an actual and not a legendary figure in the Biblical and Koranic traditions, as well as having been entombed-(in earlier times) at The Ibrahimi Mosque-Cave of the Patriarchs in the town of Hebron in the Palestinian West Bank.  Both Palestinian Muslims and Israeli Jews often pray at this historically sacred house of worship into the present-day-(though in actuality, Ibrahim-Abraham's tomb is a cenotaph).

Comment: The best-(and perhaps only) primary source discussing Ibraham-Abraham's life story, is The Old Testament....and to put The Bible into proper historical perspective....The earliest stories of The Old Testament, including the life of Ibrahim-Abraham, were initially written into textual form approximately 300 years after his passing.  I am no expert on the life and family of Ibrahim-Abraham and cannot possibly cite every chapter and verse on his life and times by every Historian.  However, the story of Abraham-Ibrahim, has for nearly 4000 years, appeared to have had significant......

Comment: historical and archeological legitimacy versus the so-called legendary status that some will associate with him.  It is not impossible to say that Ibrahim-Abraham was more of a legend than a historical figure, though I would challenge such claims to be proven....archeologically and not necessarily in historical terms alone.